# vary the LinkedCell of spin button to current selection?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have been doing battle with coding a spin button in my spreadsheet for the last hour or so... Basically I want to be able to select a cell and have it linked to the only spin button so that it can alter the cell's value. My code below should work however when I run it no matter which cell I select the LinkedCell property of the spin button becomes empty... Please help I'm all out of ideas.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Intersect(Range(Cells(42, 2), Cells(44, 18)), Target) Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub
Spinner1.LinkedCell = Target.Address
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...
the issue is that I was using R1C1 referencing style, so the LinkedCell property only accepts range in that R1C1 format. However Target.Address only returns A1 style range and is therefore denied by the spinbutton...
yay